# Sharing screen snippets from Windows 10 to iPad 7

Tags: ios, windows, screen-capture, screen-sharing

Is there a good way to share screen snippets taken with <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to an iPad?

Window's cloud clipboard requires Microsoft launcher.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the individual manufacturers go (Apple and Microsoft), their universal clipboards are for products in their eco system.  In other words, Apple's universal clipboard only works between Apple devices (i.e. macOS to iOS).  Same with Microsoft.

However, you have a couple of options:

- Save your snipit to a file and save that file to a cloud service like [OneDrive](https://onedrive.com) or [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/).  There are Microsoft OneDrive clients for macOS and iOS and reciprocally there are iCloud clients for Windows.
- Use a 3rd party utility like [1Clipboard](http://1clipboard.io/) that will allow you to sync a clipboard between Windows and macOS (requires Google drive)

Personally, I use the first option and simply save any image I obtain from my Windows machine to a OneDrive folder and pick it up on my Mac through the OneDrive folder there.  The clipboard could be more convenient but I'm not keen on having Google products installed, but if it's something you already use then it's an easy integration.